# Every compact and convex set contains center of its minimum bounding ball

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be compact and convex subset of finite dimensional normed space $X$. Let $p$ be the center of minimum bounding ball of $A$ i.e. ball with the smallest radius containing $A$. Is it true that $x\in A$? What if $X$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: The bounding ball must intersect $A$ in a collection of points - at least two and a maximum of dim$(X)+1$  - that are in general postition. The simplex having those points as vertices will be entirely contained in the ball, and the center of the ball will be in the interior of the simplex.

Comment: I meant the simplex will be contained in $A$ (by convexity), not just the ball.

Comment: To prove it, suppose you have a simplex generated by points of intersection between $A$ and the ball, then show that if the center of the ball is not in the hyperplane of the simplex, then there has to be an additional point of intersection not in that hyperplane, or else a smaller ball would be possible by moving the center towards that hyperplane.

Comment: It's not true that there are at most $\dim(x)+1$ points of intersection (Let for example $A$ be the unit ball). You also assume $\dim(X)<\infty$, but what about infinietly many dimensional case?

Comment: However maybe the last part of your proof works without introducing simplices. I'm just not sure how to formalize "moving the center towards the hyperplane".

Comment: (1) I said intersection points *in general position*. You cannot have more points in general position than one more than the dimension of the space (2) I believe that the remarks in the first comment are still true when $X$ is infinite dimensional (though perhaps the "simplex" terminology is not applicable anymore). However, the proof method I am thinking of requires inducting, which only proves it for finite dimensions. (3) Simplices (higher-dimensional triangles/tetrahedrons) are essential for the proof.

Comment: (4) show that there is a minimum distance > 0 between $A$ and the half-sphere on the side away from the hyperplane. Draw the perpendicular line segment to the hyperplane from the center, and choose the point half that distance away from the center. Make that point your new center and choose the new radius to make the same intersection with the hyperplane, which will be smaller since the new center is closer to the hyperplane. $A$ will necessarily be in the new ball.

Comment: Actually I see a problem with what I just outlined. Below the hyperplane, the new sphere will contain the old sphere, and above the original center, the distance restriction ensures $A$ is still inside. But in the section between those two, it may not be possible to shrink the radius as described while still bounding $A$.